# Building a highly scalable, failure tolerant flash sales backend

Tags: java, distributed-system, countdownlatch

I have concert tickets to sell, 1.000.000 of them. They are very popular, and as soon as the order button goes live, I will have a very high load of people trying to get them. Lets say 10.000 requests in parallel as worst case.

I want to sell at most 1.000.000 tickets, not 1.000.001. The actual order processing can be asynchronous using a queue, but the customer should have instant feedback if he got the ticket or not.

The system should survive the failure of a single server instance, so I want a fully distributed solution or at least master-slave.

My first thought: a CountDownLatch built using Zookeeper + Curator. Are there better approaches?

Comment: There's also a distributed `CountDownLatch` in Apache Ignite. (No experience with it, just googled "distributed CountDownLatch".)

Comment: Saw that, but found no Jepsen test results. Might also be overkill, as we require no persistence.

Comment: As there could be many solution, I would suggest you could try `redis`'s increment with **automic lua** script.